# can transfer data between two routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js

## First route

- "Students_details.json" has a Student array = ID,Name,Grade

  ```
  app.get('/students/:id',function(req ,res){

      fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "Students_details.json", 'utf8',function(err,data){

                //http://localhost:8081/students/3
                // it give all the details according to the ID no 3 in "Students" array located in 
                   "Students_details.json"
  ```

  }

## second route

- "parent.json" has a Student array = pID,fullname

  ```
  app.get('/getFullStudentDetails/:id',function(req , res){

        fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "parent.json", 'utf8',function(err,data){

              //so i want to do this here............
              //when i call this route i want to display first route details + second route details
              //but how??? how to transfer data first route to second route? can i do that?

          }
  ```

Comment: These routes will run independently of one another - they will handle two separate requests. If you want the `/getFullStudentDetails` to display "first route details" then you will have to make the same exact `fs.readFile` call to `students_details.json` that you're doing in the `first route` plus the `fs.readFile` call to `parent.json` in the `second route`, combine results and return/do whatever you need to.

Comment: thank you! i created like this two read files in second route. but there is a two parameters (err,data) in these two read files. when i call first route array details go in to the second route because of fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "parent.json", 'utf8',function(err,data). when i call second route there also show second route details in that fs.readFile in "data" parameter how can i separate that??????

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, what do you mean by "when i call first route array details go in to the second route"?

Comment: Now when when i give a request to first route (http://localhost:8081/getFullStudentDetails/2) it response ID,Name,Grade. that is the first array details.its correct!. But i want this, when i give a request to my next route (http://localhost:8081/students/2) i want to display ID,Name,Grade,FullName. FullName, but now display only full name and its ID num. this routes execute independently.  when i call the my next route i want to get before route details also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these APIs are being hit frontend, you can store the data in a cookie or a JWT, and read the data from the cookie or JWT in second call.

You can set the cookie with [res.cookie()](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.cookie) and read the cookie with [req.cookies()](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.cookies).

Comment: OK. i don't have an idea about cookies in JavaScript. can you tell me am i want to create cookies within the second route? can you give me a example using my question???

Comment: Set the cookie in first API, read the cookie in second API. Check the links I've shared to understand how to do that.

Comment: thank you i did that but. when i debug there show first API details in second API, but desplay in web browser [Object:Object]:[Object:Object]. how to fix